# Is this guy's thinking more inclined towards Kant's philosophy or utilitarianism

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind

Suppose there is a young adult guy who is suffering from chronic illness.
He recently lost his job because of his illness and feels things are only going to get worst for him in the future with his health.

There is a relative of his who learns about his situation and offers to support him financially so he can try again.

But the guy is refusing to take the financial support and saying it's better this support is given to someone, you know, who is more promising investment, someone younger and healthier, for the greater good.

Comment: Is this a test or HW question?

Comment: My thought...I am a newbie in philosophy. Sorry if this is a dumb relation.

Comment: How much do you know about Kant and utilitarianism?

Comment: The basic definitions...
watched some basic videos on youtube.
Kant is like being batman, he won't kill the joker.
Utilitarianism is like killing 1 to save 5 others in the trolly problem.

Comment: Please don't insult me, my mind isn't well. I know I haven't done much homework.

Comment: It is not an insult, I am trying to understand what you would recognize as a separating line between Kant and utilitarianism. The expression "for the greater good" is a tell as to what this is, see [common good](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/common-good/#FirsContWelfCons). Kant [opposed consequentialism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/65696/9148) that common good appeals to. But without that, one could find Kantian motivations to refuse money too.

Comment: @Shad: We should keep in mind that not all decisions reflect a *philosophy*. Philosophy is a system for creating a clear and self-consistent worldview from which one can make decisions. But many decisions are made from disordered, partial, emotion-driven perspectives. Perhaps this man is working from a philosophy; more likely he's merely depressed and angry; lashing out at others because he himself is in pain.